# How to prevent postgresql statement taking a lock for too long?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to tell postgres to "**abort any statement that has *acquired* and is holding a lock for more than a specified number of milliseconds**"?

I've found these two statements in postgres:

- **statement_timeout**: Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of milliseconds
- **lock_timeout**: Abort any statement that waits longer than the specified number of milliseconds while attempting to acquire a lock

Details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-client.html

However, neither quite does what I need.  The first is too generic (applies to statements that haven't acquired a lock), while the second will abort the wrong statement (i.e. the one that is waiting; not the one that has acquired it).

FYI: Our use case for this is for automatically aborting database migrations that might cause an outage.